# WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using socket io and flask application.Everthing works except I always get this message.
This is my initialization:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = APP_SECRET_KEY
jwt = JWTManager(app)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
# app.config['transports'] = 'websocket'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode='threading')

socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

What may cause this warning and what does it mean?

The console looks like this:
[image]

- tried already to install gevent and eventlet and it didn't remove the message

Comment: Have the same issue: when I install `eventlet` or `gevent` my emits stop working. Have you solved the issue yet?

Answer (score 14):

If it's the problem occurred when executing a python file
Just try `pip install eventlet` its worked for me you can also try `pip install gevent` some times this can also do the trick!

Answer (score 9):

Normally you do not include the `async_mode` option when you instantiate your server. By having `async_mode='threading'` you are forcing the server to ignore eventlet and/or gevent and go with the more basic server, which does not support WebSocket.

So remove `async_mode`, then install eventlet (or gevent and gevent-websocket). Now your server will have access to WebSocket and will not show the warning.

Comment: If I remove this then the requests block the main thread and the listening to emits doesnt work

Comment: Okay, then you will not be able to use eventlet or gevent and consequently your server will not support WebSocket, so it will have downgraded performance, hence the warning. I would try to address the blocking so that you can use WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install simple-websocket`

```py
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
    socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='threading', transports=['websocket'])

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).