# Debug from pgAdmin on windows

Tags: postgresql, debugging, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

I have os windows_10 (64bit), database postgresql-12, pgadmin4 v6.10. Requests to database and functions works from pgAdmin. Problem with Debug option. If right-click on  function to call `Debugging -> Set Breakpoint`, then the tab of this function will open in the program window with: `"Waiting for another session to invoke the target"` and waiting forever. If call `Debugging -> Debug`, then a tab will open with control buttons. But the movement of `Step` through the code always hangs after about a minute and everything is blocked, for example, at the 30th step - or at the 50th, if pass `Step` quickly. If click `Start` instead of `Step`, then code of the function is executed without problems. In pgAdmin 4: `File -> Runtime -> View log`

```
      ...

      - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
      - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 5050
      - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
      - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
      ...

      - SESSIONNAME: Console
      - SystemDrive: C:
      - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
      - windir: C:\Windows
      --------------------------------------------------------

      2023-05-16 12:34:06,492: WARNING  werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. 
      Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

      * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin' (lazy loading)
      * Environment: production
        WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
        Use a production WSGI server instead.
      * Debug mode: off
```

Does this apply to this issue? If the remark `WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance` from log is related to my problem, I found this link *[WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991897/websocket-transport-not-available-install-eventlet-or-gevent-and-) gevent-websock*
but on the recommendation of Miguel Grinberg this topic has reviews in other sources, which did not help to solve the problem. In addition, I did not understand what to do. Help, please.